# Replacing `eval` in python for a dynamic input

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I am trying to replace `eval` in a python code. I am using a configuration file to read and create a string `command` in python syntax which is later executed using `eval`.
There are two functions:

1. Reads the configuration file and creates a string which can be executed using `eval`. Example: `'raw_bytes[26:31].hex()+","+codecs.decode(raw_bytes[41:42],\"cp500\")+","+raw_bytes[48:49].hex()+","+raw_bytes[102:106].hex()'`

> ```
> def extractor_command(config_file):
>     START=0
>     CMD=""
>     with open(config_file,'r') as f:
>         next(f) #skipping the comments in the first line        
>         for line in f:
>             col = line.split()
>             UPTO=START+int(col[2])
>             if col[3] == "1":
>                 if col[3] == "0":
>                     CMD=CMD+'raw_bytes[{}:{}].hex()'.format(str(START),str(UPTO))  
>                     CMD=CMD+"+\",\"+"
>                 if col[3] == "1":
>                     CMD=CMD+'codecs.decode(raw_bytes[{}:{}],"cp500")'.format(str(START),str(UPTO))
>                     CMD=CMD+"+\",\"+" 
>             elif col[2] == "0":
>                 pass
>             START=UPTO
>         CMD=CMD.rstrip('+\",\"+')
>     return CMD
> ```

The configuration file looks like this:

```
Nr          Active  Length(bytes) String
Field1      1       8               1
Field2      0       2               0
Field3      1       4               1
...
Field250    1       1               0
Field251    0       1               1
Field252    0       2               1
```

2. The second function, will read a binary file and will use the command created in the 1st function to extract from the binary file. The extracted lines are written into a txt file.

> ```
> def extract(in_file,out_file,cmd):      
>     READBLOCKS=2052 
>     compiled = compile(cmd, '<string>', 'eval')    
>     with open(out_file,'w') as extracted_file:
>         f=open(in_file, 'rb')
>         while True:
>             raw_bytes = f.read(READBLOCKS)
>             row=eval(compiled)
>             extracted_file.write(row+'\n')
>             b=f.read(1)
>             if not b:
>                 break   
>         f.close()
> ```

Although this works fine I am looking for another solution to make the code more readable and avoid eval for security reasons. Also I don't want to create the command to extract everytime a portion of the binary file is read, because it impacts the performance (binary file is huge).
The code doesn't look pretty but it's just for demonstration.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Start by writing an example of the function you are generating dynamically, then figure out how to parameterize it so that it can be called on the data you read from the configuration file.

Comment: ...also, keep in mind that you can write a function that returns a function, or a class with a `__call__()` method, such that an instance of the class can be _called_ as a function.

Comment: It's probably fine (security-wise) to use `eval()` so long as the input to it doesn't depend on _any_ outside inputs.

Comment: Writing other functions with all proper variables, and orchestrating them properly should achieve the same goal in a much more readable way I think.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but I haven't been able to find a solution that works as fast as using `eval`. I made the code look better using `classes` with a method that reads from configuration file as a class `property` but it impacts the speed. I am looking at the suggestion to use `__call__` or function that returns a function. If I find any solution I will post it.

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this problem yet. If you have any ideas can you please post it?